# Opening of PDF file through typing of path in Url

Tags: android, pdf, url, webview

webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://xyz.info/bare_acts/Crpc.pdf"); works in Android
but webview.loadUrl (http://xyz.info/bare_acts/Crpc.pdf");  does not work
while typing
http://xyz.info/bare_acts/Crpc.pdf directly in address bar works and open the file

Answer (score 1):

webview.loadUrl (http://xyz.info/bare_acts/Crpc.pdf");
doesn't work because you are referencing the file directly, the webview might treat it like a download.

I would strongly recommend you use a library to load you pdfs as it would give your app more professionalism.

You can try this [PDF VIEWER](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

Thanks